# How Can I pass array value one by one in python

Tags: python

I wanted to pass array value to another python file but have no idea how to do that.

Another python file takes value as

```
myfile.py -y value1 -u urllist
```

how to pass value to that python file one by one. Any suggestion will be great

Comment: Use the `subprocess` module to execute shell commands from the main script.

Comment: Why are you doing it by running a separate script? Why not turn `myfile.py` into a module so you can import it and call the functions directly?

Answer (score 0):

An idea is to `import myfile.py` and then call the function programatically. Alternatively, you may use `subprocess.call`. Not recommended, but would be something like:

```
subprocess.call(["myfile.py", "-y", value1, "-u", urllist], shell=True)
```

Comment: Suggestion: Change “The best idea” to “An idea”, as the former is based on opinion (in this context).

Comment: when I try to pass the argument, it displays this error:
 "error: unrecognized arguments: emp"

Comment: @JohnLee I have the impression this is due to the file you are invoking and/or the `value` and `urllist` values you are passing. Try some error checking (perhaps you can share your case?)